# No output and error file after running job in TORQUE

Tags: debian, cluster, torque

I installed mpich-3.2.1, torque-5.1.0 and maui-3.3.1 on Debian 9.
I have one master and one node.
I use NFS file system for sharing, and ssh passwordless.
When I run a job with a user that this user is the owner of shared directory, everything is OK, and I have ERROR and OUTPUT files in this user home's directory.
But when I run a job with another user, I cant see ERROR and OUTPUT file in its home directory, and the State of *qstat* is *E*.
**Where** are **ERROR** and **OUTPUT** files?!

Answer (score 0):

Find it!
For the first time, connect master and node via ssh and answer ***yes*** to the question.